# How to install multiple versions of git simultaneously?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, git, versions

I had git v1.9.1 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

The executable is `/usr/bin/git` and I decided to try the latest and greatest v2.6.1.

I cloned the repo, compiled and installed it into `/usr/local/bin`. Now I want to be able to try it conveniently without introducing too much changes to my system.

- I couldn't really use update-alternatives as /usr/bin/git is an executable.
- I am not sure if renaming git to git-1.9.1 or something and then linking to it is safe.
- I did not want to overwrite the existing installation, since I want to keep both.
- I would prefer not to change $PATH if I don't have to.

What is the recommended course of action in this case, that will allow me to alternate between the two versions, referencing the chosen one as `git` each time? Am I doing it all wrong?

I believe that this question applies to pretty many other cases, so it makes an interesting general question:

How to have another version of a program that is already installed directly into /usr/bin without messing up the system?